# How do I include getline?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string firstName[20];
    string lastName[20];
    string fullName[40];
    string friendsName;
    cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    getline(cin, fullName);
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps telling me that I do not include the things I need to include to have `getline`.

Comment: `fullName` is an array of 40 `string`s, not a single `string`.

Comment: Please copy and paste your exact error message into the question body.

Comment: Change `string fullName[40];` to `string fullName;` do similar to firstName and lastName. You don't want an array of 40 names.

Comment: These are the error codes
eo304
c2665

Comment: To expand on the above: You have included everything you need. Unfortunately you are calling `getline` with a datatype it doesn't know how to deal with, a `string` array, so the compiler goes looking for yet another `getline` overload, that does not exist, that can work with a `string` array.

Comment: it needs to be that size but not an array.

Comment: std::string does not work that way. It will allocate the needed size depending on the input from getline().

Comment: Error numbers are close to worthless for a lot of us (we're using different compilers). Down at the bottom near the Error List tab you'll find  the Output tab. In the Output tab you'll find the complete and unadulterated build output as plain text. You can copy the text and paste it into the question. Note that often the complete build output contains the extra hints you need to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: it has no instance of overload function matches the argument list

Comment: also the secound error says that it cannot convert the data types.

Comment: Add those to the question so all of the information is in one place. This make understanding the question easier for future askers with a similar problem. If they can better understand the question, they can usually better understand the answers. Side note: The second error is a common result of the first.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` is a variable-length container of characters.  You don't need to specify its max size when you declare it, and you certainly don't use `[]` syntax to do that.

`string firstName[20];` is an array of 20 C++ strings.

`char firstName[20];` is an array of 20 characters, which can be thought of as a single C-style string.

`std::getline()` wants a single `std::string` to populate, not an array of `std::string`s.  All of your `string[]` arrays should be single `std::string`s instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string fullName;

    cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    getline(cin, firstName);

    cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    getline(cin, lastName);

    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    cout << "Welcome " << fullName << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing C-style strings with `std::string`.

```
// C-style
char str[40];

// std::string
std::string str;
```

This:

```
string fullName[40];
```

is an array of 40 strings, not a single string of 40 characters.

Comment: This is useful information, but it doesn't explain to OP how to solve the problem, or why creating an array of strings causes an error with `std::getline`.